# Javascript hovering effect

Tags: javascript, image, background, hover

Is there a Javascript tutorial or code to make a subtle image hover or move in the background, like the effect on http://www.saratusar.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the img or div in an anchor tag, you can apply an effect using pure CSS. (This appears to be the technique used by the site you're referencing.)

HTML:

```
<a id="thing" href="javascript:void(0);"><div></div></a>
```

CSS:

```
#thing div { background: url(image.jpg); width: 100px; height: 100px; min-height: 100px; }
#thing:hover div { background: url(image2.jpg); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about these buttons on top, check out CSS (Cascading Style Sheet). More effects using JS and CSS you can get by using JavaScript JQuery Library.

Good luck!